# What is the code to create the Centered Moving Average in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

i can't find the way to create the Centered Moving Average in pinescript. The Centered Moving Average works in this way:
Instead of the simple moving average I need the centered moving average. The centered moving average (if for example I have 20 daily closings and I look for the Centered moving average at 10, I receive the first data on the fifth day and the last data on the fourteenth day, so I have 5 days left uncovered, to remedy this I have to give the last value to the uncovered data the closing price of the last day (please see attached image)

I need the Centered Moving Average instead of std. MA in the Bollinger Bands

Comment: insufficient definition of centered MA to help out here

Answer (score 0):

You can offset the plot of MA to the left with negative value, that will shift it to center position, but leave uncovered gap of missing points to the right.

```js
//@version=5
indicator('CombinedArray', overlay = true)

len = input.int(10, "length", minval = 1, maxval = 5000)
ma1 = ta.wma(close, len)
Shift = math.abs(len / 4)
plot(ma1, 'MA Centered unfinished', color.new(color.aqua, 0), 6, offset = -Shift)
```

If you need to cover missing points you have to shift data Array as your MA source, then cover the gap with array.push or alike. I believe using Array function would make fastest and leanest code. Arrays are complicated though. You can place your post under Array Youtube Videos to make the request publicly visible
to be solved under Mozilla copyright (will take some time), or just hire a coder and spare some cash, or learn Array coding (will take time and work). Problem - Array documentation is scars, VOGUE and lacks practical samples across all languages types. Lots of coders keep it secret I believe on purpose. Try to post under those Videos for request gaining traction if you want an eventual freebee [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lYRQgwahdU&t=932s